# Custom JS selector is not taking effect at ngModel

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have created a custom selector system with JS trying to make it look better. It looks perfect and changes the selector when I make it visible, but it doesn't changes my ngModel at my Angular component, keeping it at undefined. Here is my JS and HTML.

```html
<div class="form__select">
  <select id="gender" name="gender" #gender="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.occupation">
    <option value="0">Selecciona un género</option>
    <option value="1">Hombre</option>
    <option value="2">Mujer</option>
    <option value="3">Otro</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```html
 load_selector() {
    const selectors: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName("form__select");
    document.addEventListener("click", MainScript.close_selector);
    [].forEach.call(selectors, (selector) => {
      const select: any = selector.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      let replaced: HTMLElement = document.createElement("DIV");
      replaced.setAttribute("class", "form__select-box");
      replaced.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      selector.appendChild(replaced);
      let option_parent: HTMLElement = document.createElement("DIV");
      option_parent.setAttribute("class", "form__select-items");
      [].forEach.call(select.options, (options) => {
        let option: HTMLElement = document.createElement("DIV");
        option.setAttribute("class", "form__select-item");
        option.innerHTML = options.innerHTML;
        option.addEventListener("click", function () {
          const parent_node: any = (<HTMLElement>(<HTMLElement>(<HTMLElement>this.parentNode)).parentNode).getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
          let previous_sibling: any = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
          for (let i = 0; i < parent_node.length; i++) {
            if (parent_node.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
              parent_node.selectedIndex = i;
              previous_sibling.innerHTML = (<HTMLElement>this).innerHTML;
              let actual_selected = (<HTMLElement>(<HTMLElement>this.parentNode)).getElementsByClassName("form__select-item--selected");
              [].forEach.call(actual_selected, (node) => {
                node.classList.remove("form__select-item--selected");
                node.classList.add("class", "form__select-item");
              });
              this.classList.add("form__select-item--selected");
            }
          }
          previous_sibling.click();
        });
        option_parent.appendChild(option);
      });
      selector.appendChild(option_parent);
      replaced.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        (<any>this).nextSibling.classList.toggle("form__select-items--active");
        (<any>this).classList.toggle("form__select-box--active");
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Please describe your goals more detailled and maybe provide a stackblitz example.
The code you posted does not rely on angular mechanics. I would recommend trying to solve issues 'the angular way' instead of manipulating HTML Nodes directly via javascript.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom Dropdown selector, like <select> one, but I dont know why ngModel doesnt get the selector value